# Anti-self-dual connections on CP^2

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, connections

I'm learning Yang-Mills theory and its applications on 4-manifold. 
I want to know that have someone computed all the anti-self-dual connections on principle 
$SU(2)$ bundles over complex projective space $CP^2$. Where can I find the original paper 
if someone has calculated it?

Comment: Donaldson-Kronheimer's book **The Geometry of Four-Manifolds** computes the moduli space for small 2nd Chern class (it's empty for $c_2=1$); check the examples in chapter 4. But it's not computed by explicitly writing down connections (compared to the $S^4$ scenario). You should be able to find appropriate references there.

Comment: You also have the Atiyah-Drinfeld-Hitchin-Manin construction http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ADHM_construction, on one side, and twistor space of Atiyah-Hitchin-Singer, or actually and originally R Penrose, on the other, which leads to complex algebraic geometry and results of Horrocks, Barth and Hartshorne. The twistor space of CP2 is the flag manifold F(C3)...